# How Can I get Desired output without modifying the code

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

```
var demo = { counter : 5 ,getCounter: () => this.counter};

console.log(demo.getCounter())
```

will print undefined;

how Can it print 5 without modifying the code(means by using arrow function only)

I tried `apply`,`bind` function But Nothing works

Comment: `var demo = { counter : 5 ,getCounter: () => return demo.counter};`. The arrow function binds `this` to the scope in which `demo` is declared.

Comment: return is implicit with arrow functions without brackets

Comment: @OriDrori but without modifying demo object.

Comment: @SvenWritesCode yes it was a mistake it should be var demo = { counter : 5 ,getCounter: () => this.counter};

Comment: @Adityakumar - without changing demo code? Override demo.getCounter after the object was declared.